# Mock method to return a value only when passed any *non-null* object of a given class

Tags: java, mocking, mockito, matcher, hamcrest

I'm using Mockito to mock a method to return a Date when given a Date.

```
when(supplier.calculateDeliveryDate(any(Date.class)))
    .thenReturn(supplierDeliveryDate);
```

However, I only want it to return the `supplierDeliveryDate` when it is passed a *non-null* Date object.
When passed `null`, it should return null.

Is this possible? How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an anonymous inner class:

```
// unit test
public OrderServiceTest {

    // instance of class-under-test
    private OrderService instance;
    // stub value
    private Date supplierDeliveryDate = new Date();

    // mock as an anonymous inner class
    private Supplier supplier = new Supplier() {
        public Date calculateDeliveryDate(Date input) {
            if (input == null) {
                return null;
            }
            else {
                return supplierDeliveryDate;
            } 
        }
    };

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        instance = new OrderService();

        // dependency injection
        instance.setSupplier(supplier);
    }

    @Test
    public void testOrderHappy() {
        // SETUP
        Date orderDate = new Date();            

        // CALL
        Date result = instance.order(orderDate);

        // VERIFY
        assertTrue(supplierDeliveryDate == result);
    }

    @Test
    public void testOrderNull() {
        // SETUP
        Date orderDate = null;

        // CALL
        Date result = instance.order(orderDate);

        // VERIFY
        assertNull(result);
    }
}
```

But you should really wonder why you need this kind of behavior.

If you write a well defined test case then you should know exactly how often, and with which arguments, your mock is called. If so, then you can just stub the expected calls instead of wiring your mock with conditional behavior.

Note that is is useful if your test is as 'sharp' as possible. If a different number of calls hits your mock than expected, or with different arguments, then the test should fail.

Comment: Unfortunately your code example does not relate tor the question since it changes the production code behavior rather than the test code as the OP requested. but I like your statement in your answer. I'd vote up if you delete the example...

Comment: @Adriaan I'm adding to an existing test. The test passes when the given date is null, but the production code ends up throwing a NullPointerException. I'd like to make minimal changes to the existing test, but have it test this case of the null Date.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle `Supplier.calculateDeliveryDate(...)` was being mocked anyway, so it wasn't production code.

Comment: I've decided to go with this. It's not as pretty as using a later version of Mockito with `ArgumentMatchers`, but it's quick and easy and it works.

Comment: Thanks. I use this construction a lot when I want some more control than simple mocks. You can also do stuff like this with Mockito's Answer API btw.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle : you are probably not familiar with this style of mocking. I will change the example a bit to show you why it is perfectly valid, and does not 'change production code' in any way.

Comment: Note: the use of an anonymous inner class for mocking becomes tedious if the mocked class has many abstract methods. To mitigate that you could create a top-level class which extends the mocked class to achieve the same result (so at least you only have to implement the unused methods only once)

Comment: @AdriaanKoster *"you are probably not familiar with this style of mocking"* I did this kind of mocking before I dicovered Mockito... ;o)

Comment: @TimothyTruckle So then why the misguided remark at the top of this string of comments?

Comment: @AdriaanKoster *"So then why the misguided remark at the top of this string of comments?"* I missed that you proposal was in the test class.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ArgumentMatchers.isNull()` matcher.

```
when(supplier.calculateDeliveryDate(any(Date.class)))
    .thenReturn(supplierDeliveryDate);
when(supplier.calculateDeliveryDate(isNull()))
    .thenReturn(null);
```

Comment: It looks like this might work, but I'd need to upgrade our version of Mockito to 2. That breaks all the code that uses un-type-safe `anyList()`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use helper method:

```
public static <T> void validateAndMock(Supplier<T> ongoingStubbing, T mockedResponse) {
    if (mockedResponse != null) {
        when(ongoingStubbing.get()).thenReturn(mockedResponse);
    }
}
```

And then call:

```
validateAndMock(() -> supplier.calculateDeliveryDate(any(Date.class)), supplierDeliveryDate);
```